# Algorithm for parsing expressions in python?

Tags: python, parsing, expression-evaluation

I have next algorithm for parsing expressions in Python:

```
def parse(strinput):
  for operator in ["+-", "*/"]:
    depth = 0
    for p in range(len(strinput) - 1, -1, -1):
      if strinput[p] == ')': depth += 1
      elif strinput[p] == '(': depth -= 1
      elif depth==0 and strinput[p] in operator:
        # strinput is a compound expression
        return (strinput[p], parse(strinput[:p]), parse(strinput[p+1:]))
  strinput = strinput.strip()
  if strinput[0] == '(':
    # strinput is a parenthesized expression?
    return parse(strinput[1:-1])
  # strinput is an atom!
  return strinput
```

(it can be found here: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=284842)

I have hard time understanding it, since I don't find Python docs very helpful for this situation. Can someone tell me what line: `for operator in ["+-", "*/"]:`means?
I know it's structure like for each string variable which is operator in array of this 2 elements, but why is it written like this ["+-, */"]? How does Python separate it? In first iteration, operator is "+-"?

Any help would mean a lot. Thanks

Comment: It looks like a very unpythonic algorithm to me, if I can tell.

Comment: `for operator in ["+-", "*/"]:` it's a loop iterating through list which has two elements "+-" and "*/"

Comment: @Elazar: What would you improve?

Comment: @Blender truth is, I don't really know. It looks too similar to something I wrote in an introduction-to-CS course. in C. Can't *you* improve it? For one, it takes advantage of the fact that an operator is single character (which breaks in python3). It just feels... awkward.

Comment: @Elazar: How would it break in Python 3?

Comment: @Blender I referred to the '//' operator.

Comment: @Elazar: Python 2 has floor division as well. This snippet isn't supposed to parse Python expressions.

Comment: @Blender Yep. got it.

Comment: @Blender: One better, though slightly more complicated, way is to use [top-down parsing](http://effbot.org/zone/simple-top-down-parsing.htm).

Comment: I think I know what bothers me: it uses both `+= 1` / `-= 1` *and* recursion. But recursion means you already have a stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct; `for operator in ["+-", "*/"]:` means operator will be `"+-"` the first time through and `"*/"` the second time through the loop.

Notice how later it checks if `strinput[p] in operator`. Python treats a string as a list of characters, so this expression will only be true if `strinput[p]` is equal to `"+"` or `"-"` on the first time through and `"*"` or `"/"` the second time through.

(The reason they do this is for order of operations- `"+"` and `"-"` get equal but lower precedence to `"*"` and `"/"`)

Comment: Yea, thank you! :) I already got by time what it means by it and exactly got it on 6*3+2. It goes from right to left, first checking lower priority operators, because it can group by them, since higher priority operators need to be executed for first. :)